# Avoid non-sequential duplicate messages on Kafka

Tags: architecture, apache-kafka

Here we have a service which produces prioritized tickets on Kafka and a second service in which human operators consumes these tickets for calling customers. The tickets are generated daily. The problem is that some customers may be pushed to Kafka on several days and we don't want to call the customer twice.

Currently, we are thinking about keeping a table to store the customers already processed and skip them in case of duplicates. Another option would be Kafka automatically skip these duplicates. So, the question is if is there a way to tell Kafka to avoid duplicating messages already processed, given a identity key?

Comment: Kafka doesn't handle this for you. You'd need to store the ids on the side in some lookup table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate messages should always be handled by the message consumer. There's no technology that completely prevent duplicates that also guarantees delivery. (As cricket_007 points out in their comment, this isn't a feature of Kafka and given this the responsibility has to fall further downstream)

At the bare minimum each message should have a unique identifier so the consumer is able to determine if it has seen it before. Having a table on the consumer side that tracks processed messages by their unique id is a common solution.